# isc-dhcpd sanity check fail even though everything looks right

Tags: dhcp, freebsd, dhcp-server

I have a machine in freebsd 8.1
and I am failing to do `service isc-dhcpd start` it keeps saying "Configuration file sanity check failed"

Hint: I copy the /usr/local.rc.d/isc-dhcpd and /usr/local/sbin/dhcpd from another freebsd 8.1 machine.

My dhcpd.conf in /usr/local/etc/ looks fine.

```
    ddns-update-style none;
    option domain-name "bitgravity.com";
    option domain-name-servers xxxxxx, yyyyyy, zzzzz;
    option ntp-servers 192.168.1.1;


subnet xxxxxx netmask xxxxxx{
    deny bootp;
    deny booting;

    range xxxx xxxx;

    option subnet-mask xxxx;
    option routers xxxx;
    option www-server xxxxx;
    option host-name "somename";

    next-server xxxxx
        filename "/pxelinux.0";
     }
```

For all the "xxx" , "yyy", "zzz" i am pretty sure i input the parameters correctly as I've done this a lot of times. i am suspecting isc-dhcpd is reading from somewhere else which is highly unlikely. Can anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should check in `/var/log/messages`

The DHCP daemon will log what it did not like from the config file.